# Javascript code that should make a table and run on page load

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Javascript should run when the page loads, create a table with 10 rows and 10 columns and adds it to div "funky", the cells of the table should contain the text "N M" where N is the minumum of the row and  column index and M is the maximum of the row and column index,cells in even numbered columns should have the text colour purple. here are my javascript and html codes

```js
function go() {
  var ROWS = 10;
  var COLS = 10;
  var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.border = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i <= ROWS; i += 1) {
    var row = document.createElement("row");
    if (i == 2) {
      row.Fontweight = "bold";
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j += 2) {
      var col = document.createElement("cell");
      col.innerHTML = i + " " + j;
      if (j / 2 === 0) {
        col.style.color = "purple";
      }
      row.appendChild(col);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
    document.getElementsByClassName("table");
  }
}
onload = go();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
    <script src="question2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <head>
  <body>
    <div class="funky"></div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: i don't see any question here, but FYI, you're not closing HTML tags properly (e.g. `<html>` should be closed with `</html>`, not `<html>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace HTML Code To :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
    <script src="question2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:go();">
    <div class="funky"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace JS Code To :

```
function go() {
  var ROWS = 10;
  var COLS = 10;
  var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky")[0];
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.style.border = "1px solid #000";
  table.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
  for (var i = 0; i <= ROWS; i += 1) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    if (i == 2) {
      row.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j += 1) {
      var col = document.createElement("td");
      col.innerHTML = i + " " + j;
      if (j % 2 === 0) {
        col.style.color = "purple";
      }
      row.appendChild(col);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  out.appendChild(table);
}
```

You need to use MOD Operator to understand is it even or not. You need to use style property before using border property.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your code.

- When you use `getElementsByClassName` you need to access them by
  index like this

  `var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky")[0];`
- You need to append `table` after creating it to `div` then it will be
  show on page.
- You need to create `tr` instead of `row` and `td` instead of `cell`.

  ```
  function go() {
          var ROWS = 10;
          var COLS = 10;
          var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky")[0];
          var table = document.createElement("table");
          table.border = 1;
          for (var i = 0; i <= ROWS; i ++) {
              var row = document.createElement("tr");
              if (i == 2) {
                  row.style.fontWeight = "bold";
              }
              for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j += 2) {
                  var col = document.createElement("td");
                  col.innerHTML = i + " " + j;
                  if (j / 2 === 0) {
                      col.style.color = "purple";
                  }
                  row.appendChild(col);
              }
              table.appendChild(row);
              document.getElementsByClassName("table");
          }
          out.appendChild(table);
      }
  ```

Comment: And you got several mistakes too mate.

Comment: @ErolKESKİN you may correct in answer.

Comment: I corrected it sir.